# "out of shared memory" and lock monitoring in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, memory

I'm trying to monitor an application that uses PostgreSQL (13) to identify what can cause this error (occasionally):

```
ERROR: out of shared memory
Hint: You might need to increase max_pred_locks_per_transaction.
```

I've increase the `max_pred_locks_per_transaction` (and `max_locks_per_transaction`), but I'm trying to find the potential cause in the application itself, to see if something better can be done about it.

When I monitor the locks, there are sometimes `SIReadLock` that seem to be running for a relatively long time, all hung up on `COMMIT` (although they do finish eventually).
A number of the queries executed are likely to involve after-insert/update triggers.

Is there a way to monitor exactly which queries are creating those locks (as opposed to just seeing `COMMIT` at the end)?
(Is there a general recommended way to investigate this sort of problems?)

Here is the query to monitor the locks:

```sql
SELECT pg_database.datname AS database,
       pg_namespace.nspname AS schema,
       pg_class.relname AS table,
       pg_locks.mode AS lock_mode,
       pg_locks.page AS lock_page,
       pg_locks.tuple AS lock_tuple,
       pg_locks.locktype AS lock_type,
       pg_locks.virtualxid AS virtual_xid,
       pg_locks.virtualtransaction AS virtual_transaction,
       pg_locks.transactionid AS transaction_id,
       AGE(now(), pg_stat_activity.query_start) AS time_running,
       pg_stat_activity.query_start AS time_started,
       pg_stat_activity.query
FROM pg_class
    INNER JOIN pg_locks ON pg_locks.relation = pg_class.oid
    INNER JOIN pg_database ON pg_database.oid = pg_locks.database
    INNER JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace
    INNER JOIN pg_stat_activity ON pg_stat_activity.pid = pg_locks.pid
WHERE pg_class.relkind = 'r'
    ORDER BY 11 DESC;
```

Here is a sample output (more rows not displayed):

```
   table       |    lock_mode    | lock_page | lock_tuple | lock_type | virtual_xid | virtual_transaction| transaction_id |  time_running   |         time_started          |    query
---------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------+----------------+-----------------+-------------------------------+--------------
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8410 |            | page      |             | 25/298509          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8416 |            | page      |             | 25/295398          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_b  | SIReadLock      |           |            | relation  |             | 25/299949          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8411 |            | page      |             | 25/296128          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_c  | SIReadLock      |           |            | relation  |             | 25/297437          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8413 |            | page      |             | 25/300961          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8405 |            | page      |             | 25/294361          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8403 |        110 | tuple     |             | 25/300599          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8419 |            | page      |             | 25/298137          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_d  | SIReadLock      |           |            | relation  |             | 25/296086          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8413 |            | page      |             | 25/294361          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8421 |            | page      |             | 25/298137          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8422 |            | page      |             | 25/296692          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_b  | SIReadLock      |           |            | relation  |             | 25/300080          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8405 |            | page      |             | 25/299590          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_c  | SIReadLock      |           |            | relation  |             | 25/294222          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_b  | SIReadLock      |           |            | relation  |             | 25/299148          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8407 |            | page      |             | 25/296692          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_d  | SIReadLock      |           |            | relation  |             | 25/295640          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8431 |            | page      |             | 25/298779          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8426 |            | page      |             | 25/294976          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8410 |            | page      |             | 25/297792          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8416 |            | page      |             | 25/294361          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8426 |            | page      |             | 25/300585          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8417 |          1 | tuple     |             | 25/297792          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_c  | SIReadLock      |           |            | relation  |             | 25/295787          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_e  | SIReadLock      |           |            | relation  |             | 25/297764          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8421 |            | page      |             | 25/295893          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8427 |            | page      |             | 25/294719          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_d  | SIReadLock      |           |            | relation  |             | 25/297663          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_c  | SIReadLock      |           |            | relation  |             | 25/294139          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8431 |            | page      |             | 25/300947          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_d  | SIReadLock      |           |            | relation  |             | 25/295370          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8422 |            | page      |             | 25/297792          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_c  | SIReadLock      |           |            | relation  |             | 25/297064          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8410 |            | page      |             | 25/299949          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8415 |            | page      |             | 25/296128          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8428 |            | page      |             | 25/300080          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8431 |            | page      |             | 25/297423          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8417 |          1 | tuple     |             | 25/298509          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8408 |            | page      |             | 25/297064          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8427 |            | page      |             | 25/295384          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8425 |            | page      |             | 25/294236          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
 test_table_a  | SIReadLock      |      8415 |            | page      |             | 25/294361          |                | 00:45:46.929129 | 2021-09-06 12:13:31.525553+01 | COMMIT
```

(There's generally fewer than 30 connections to this database server, 10 to this database.)

Answer (score 2):

`max_pred_locks_per_transaction` determines the size of the “predicate lock target hashtable”. This is a different data structure than the lock table, so you can run out of shared memory there while the lock table is not full.

It is normal that `SIReadLock`s are held after the transaction commits. Your query is misleading: those `COMMIT` s are not hanging, they are done.

Comment: Thank you. I've increased both `max_pred_locks_per_transaction` and `max_locks_per_transaction` (having seen both suggestions in error messages). As far as I understand, `pg_locks` is for both regular and predicate locks. Is there a way to track what those hanging `COMMIT` queries actually do (or perhaps track what the triggers actually do)?

Comment: I have extended the answer to cover that.

Comment: Thanks, I'd not realised they were done. Are you effectively saying that those locks effectively have nothing to do with the OOM errors I'm getting? Is it also normal for those `SIReadLock`s to be held for such a long time?

Comment: Yes, that is normal. Sure, the number of locks (or predicate lock targets) makes you go OOM. But the `COMMIT`s are completed. Just raise the limit and be happy.

Comment: I guess I'd generally be interested in having a way to monitor which queries make this number grow (possibly in order to try to improve the application that makes those queries in the first place). Somehow, I get the impression that increasing the limit (e.g. 500 at the moment for both) is only postponing the problem...

Comment: I don't know of a way to monitor that. 500 is high - do you have long running transactions? If there is really a leak, that would be a PostgreSQL bug.

Answer (score 0):

After trying one week, I did not find any good solutions to it. Eventually I managed to pin down a potential query causing this by caughting it red handed.

Increase lock usage is usually tied to a long-running query or a query that behaves irrationally. It may happen in some PSQL versions and [PSQL versions have bugs, though this is rare.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/270183/38877)

I had the same issue with `Hint: You might need to increase max_pred_locks_per_transaction.` and I had already increased `max_pred_locks_per_transaction` to 2048, a ridiculously high value.

How I tracked the underlying issue down:

1. Monitor PostgreSQL process memory. I monitored the Docker container where PSQL was running using [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/). The issue was triggering somewhat randomly and I could not find a way to monitor *per connection* or *per query* lock and memory usage. Especially, in this case, as the problematic query pretty much brought the whole database down.

[image]

2. [Monitor active queries using pg_activity](https://github.com/dalibo/pg_activity). You can do this by hand from any PSQL IDE or `psql` cli prompt, but `pg_activity` makes it much easier.

[image]

After a lot of manual monitoring, I managed to pin down the query that caused exceed lock, and therefore memory usage, increase.

3. Fix the query

In my case, the solution was to get rid of the query in the first place. Other solutions you can do

- If this application side query, split it to several query and commit batches. Make sure your application keeps the transaction open only for a short while and commits after updating hundreds or thousands of rows. Do not let a single transaction to touch multiple rows.
- Re-engine the query e.g. to use materialised views